# Apex Inheritance: illegal Assignment

Tags: apex, compile-error, inheritance

Why is the following code returning an illegal assignment error in anonymous window?

> Line: 3, Column: 9 illegal assignment from truck to vehicle

**Super Class**

```
public virtual class vehicle {

    public void model(){
         system.debug ('Model method of vehicle class ');
    }
    public void speed(){
        system.debug('Speed of the vehicle depends of the model');
    }
}
```

**Child Class**

```
public class truck extends vehicle 
{
    public override void speed()
    {
        system.debug('Truck has speed of 20 mile/hr');
    }
}
```

**Execute Anonymous Script**

```
vehicle v=new vehicle();
v.speed();
vehicle v2=new truck();
v2.speed();
v2.model();
```

Comment: Did your child class(Truck) compile successfully?

Comment: Perhaps you have a naming conflict...

Answer (score 2):

I think you may have to mark your methods as virtual too in your base class.

**

> In addition, the extending class can override the existing virtual
>   methods by using the override keyword in the method definition.

**

```
public virtual void model(){
     system.debug ('Model method of vehicle class ');
}
public virtual void speed(){
    system.debug('Speed of the vehicle depends of the model');
}
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_extending.htm

Comment: I marked all the method (model & Speed) virtual but the error is still there. The code looks good. I even tried the sample codes in the SFDC, and the error still comes up. This appears to be some compiler error... this is weird

Comment: are you updating the class through an IDE/ directly in the org? The only reason why I see you may still have error is because the classes may not be updated if done through eclipse or some other tool

Comment: I'm using the developer console on SFDC

Comment: Can you post the final classes you have in your original question

Comment: looks like the issue is with the developer console. The same code runs fine in Force.com IDE

Comment: Can you delete the workspace you currently are using and create a new workspace in developer console, then try to rerun the script?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted is valid. You should be able to assign a child class to a super variable. Likely causes for this code to fail:

- Naming conflict
- **Unnoticed compile fail**

You can run the following script in `Execute Anonymous` to demonstrate the basic concept:

```
class Vehicle { }
class Truck extends Vehicle { }
Vehicle instance = new Truck();
```

Comment: Yeah... the code looks good. I even tried the sample codes in the SFDC ==>https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_extending.htm                         and the error still comes up. This appears to be some compiler error... this is weird

Answer (score 1):

Did your truck class even compile?

I just copied your code and I had to make the speed() method virtual, in order to override it in the truck class. Once I did this it worked as you would expect.

```
//vehicle class
public virtual class vehicle {

    public void model(){
        system.debug ('Model method of vehicle class ');
    }
    public virtual void speed(){
        system.debug('Speed of the vehicle depends of the model');
    }
}

//truck class
public class truck extends vehicle { 
    public override void speed() { 
        system.debug('Truck has speed of 20 mile/hr'); 
    } 
}

//execute anonymous
vehicle v=new vehicle(); 
v.speed(); 

//truck v2 = new truck(); or vehicle v2 = new truck(); both work. 
// I find the truck v2 =... cleaner
truck v2=new truck(); 
v2.speed(); 
v2.model();
system.debug(v2);
```

Comment: Both the vehicle and truck class compiled without error... i made all the method virtual but the error still there. Your code did not assign the truck instance to the vehicle object: vehicle v2 = new truck()   this assignment should work but for some reason isn't working. This might have something to do with the compiler